# Как найти словарь по значению определённого ключа во вложенном словаре?

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь с вложенными словарями:

```
d = {'result': {'1': {'NAME': 'Саша', 'AGE': 20},
                '2': {'NAME': 'Вася', 'AGE': 30}
                }
     }
```

Необходимо вывести словарь, в котором `AGE = 30`
То есть:

```
{'NAME': 'Вася', 'AGE': 30}
```

Как это сделать? Желательно без for

Comment: Ну вам всё-равно d['result'].values надо будет перебирать. Ну или items. Но можно сделать без явного for, например через filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы из вашего словаря d достать искомый словарь, следует воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
print(list(filter(lambda v: v["AGE"]==30, d["result"].values()))[0])
```

Здесь мы фильтруем список значений, полученных из словаря, хранящегося в d["result"].
Для фильтрации используем лямбда-функцию: если у элемента v фильтруемого списка поле "AGE" равно 30, то мы сохраняем этот элемент, иначе - отбрасываем.
Полученный отфильтрованный объект переводим в список, используя list().
Из полученного списка достаём нулевой (единственный) элемент, это и будет искомый словарь.

Обратите внимание, что конечный список может содержать несколько элементов, если в исходном словаре d было несколько элементов с "AGE" равным 30. Или, например, конечный список может быть пустым, если в исходном словаре не было элементов, удовлетворяющих условию.

Comment: Такие ответы прям читать приятно

Comment: @Axaneron да некоторые книги хуже написаны (ну или в крайнем случае переведены).

Answer (score 2):

Эта программа работает через цикл for:

```
for i in d['result'].keys():
    for j in d['result'][i].keys():
        if d['result'][i][j] == 30:
            print(d['result'][i])
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install jmespath`

```py
import jmespath as jp

d = {
    'result': {
        '1': {'NAME': 'Саша', 'AGE': 20},
        '2': {'NAME': 'Вася', 'AGE': 30}
    }
}

# Если Вы уверены, что такой элемент может быть только один, 
# или Вам нужен первый. То что-то такое...
res, *_ = jp.search(
    'result.* | [?AGE==`30`]', d
) or (None,)

# Если список соответсвующих условию то лучше так
res = jp.search(
    'result.* | [?AGE==`30`]', d
)
```